# GIS Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know this GIS Stack Exchange site's birthday is coming up on **3/7/2012**? Congratulations!

How about a contest or some other fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Use this meta post or schedule a chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention (community@stackexchange.com). We're really interested in community-lead initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “go for it!”

Comment: How do you come up with that, Robert?  The [oldest question on this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15541/how-to-convert-a-line-shapefile-into-a-csv-with-nodes-and-links) is from 5 August 2010, almost five months later.  Take a look at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/548/gis-se-is-one-year-old, too, which dates the Beta to late July.

Comment: @whuber The "anniversary" is the graduation date when the site launched out of its beta.

Comment: That would be around September '10, then, right?  For example, [this question](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143/what-does-it-take-to-fulfill-my-commitment-and-get-the-beta-badge) documents the site was still in Beta on 9/9/2010.

Comment: @whuber That's all about the private beta. This is for "graduation", when the site got it's own design, etc -- http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319/new-design-launched

Comment: @RobertCartaino FTFY. :P

Comment: Ah--so you mean our *first* birthday.  I was misled by the reference to a "2nd Birthday Super Contest."

Answer (score 4):

We could run a *Where is this?* question every day for a week or so.

Hint: a hot spot in a cold place.

[image]

Update, Another clue:
[image]

Comment: I know! This is on a google-generated tile!

Comment: lol, Another hint: it is not a [Rorschach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test) showing a profile of me looking west.

Comment: [Spoiler!] French Southern and Antarctic Lands > http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-49.25,69.167&ll=-49.196064,69.222107&spn=1.193582,2.90863&t=h&z=9

Comment: I think @Mapperz deserves a (long sleeved) GIS.SE shirt.